# How do I adjust the Wordpress URL handling to ignore certain directories?

Tags: svn, wordpress, trac, dreamhost

I'm using Dreamhost's WordPress, Subversion, and Trac installations. My Subversion repositories are all in /repos/[projectname] and my Trac installations are all in /trac/[projectname]. I also have some other directories, such as /webapps/[appname] for web applications that I am working on. However, if I go to /trac/[projectname] in my browser, Wordpress serves up a 404 - which makes sense, there's no Wordpress page at that URL.

I wondered if this might be related to some plugins that I'm running. I'm going to start by disabling all of my plugins and turn them on one by one. However, I disabled them all (and even reset my theme to the default) and the same behavior was experienced.

I'm not sure if this is something I do programatically or through the administration console, and it really doesn't matter, but I didn't see anything in the console, so I'm guessing it's programatic (and that's why I'm asking here). I just need to identify directories that I don't want Wordpress to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is stock WordPress behaviour - its clean URLs work by redirecting **all** requests that don't match an existing file or directory to WordPress's `index.php`, which then handles based on the URL.

The following in your `.htaccess` *prior* to the WordPress `RewriteRule`s should exclude those directories from this behaviour.

```
RewriteRule ^(trac|repos|webapps) - [L]
```